# Dependency between 2 futures

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, concurrency, future

please see the code below.

```
int cond = true;

void f1()
{
     while(cond)
     {

     }
}

void f2()
{
     cond  = false;
}

int main()
{
     auto fut1 = std::async(f1);
     auto fut2 = std::async(f2);
     fut1.get();
     fut2.get();
}
```

My question is, will this program run infinitely on a single threaded sw/hw?
I cant test this because my std::hardware_concurrency shows 8 and I dont know a way to force a program to run on a single thread.

Comment: This program has UB regardless of any thread numbers. You have a race on `cond`.

Comment: Make `cond` atomic and then the answer is no; but I think you should do more research into threading issues and synchronisation

Comment: but fut1.get() blocks until the f1 returns right?

Comment: @EduardRostomyan  UB means anything could happen. From what you've posted, the compiler might rip out the call to `f1` completely because it has no effects; or it might assume that cond is never changed and can always be assumed to be true.

Comment: `get` only blocks if the result isnt available yet, if the thread already finished then `get` basically just returns the value. The future just holds the result, but doesnt make sure that the threads are executed in any order

Comment: nobody answered my question!! If wverything is perfect and no data race is there, and if I have a loop like that in f1, will the program finish or not? will f2 be called? Can you please answer this instead of posting a philosophy and showing of you deep knowledge of UB!

Comment: I think you may be under some misapprehension here.  Even on a single core CPU with `std::hardware_concurrency` being `1` threads can still be created.  So even if `fut1.get()` blocks `f2` will start on a new thread, set `cond = false` therefore unblocking `f1` -- subject to the `atomic` \`correction' mentioned elsewhere.

Comment: @EduardRostomyan As long as there's context switch (which means almost always) then the program won't loop forever. This isn't really related to the hardware concurrency.

Comment: "If wverything is perfect and no data race is there" ... but there is a data race

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This program would NOT run infinitely, as soon as f2() invoked by 2nd thread, it will set the **cond** to false

As per definition of [Async](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async): 
The template function **async** runs the function f asynchronously (**potentially in a separate thread which may be part of a thread pool**) and returns a std::future that will eventually hold the result of that function call.

There are 3 threads
main Thread :
f1 thread :
f2 thread :

flow will be :

1. main thread
2. f1 thread starts ---f1 body executes according to thread life cycle
3. f2 thread starts --- f2 body executes and sets *cond*

when f2 get the chance depends on the thread scheduling and blocked stated
for ex: if you have sleep in f1 and f2 will get chance

i am curious to see other's answers